# List posts that are in the same category as the current post title

Tags: posts, categories, list

How would I call out additional posts that have a tag by that matches the current post's title?
For example if the current posts is titled "opossum" I would like teasers from all posts tagged with "opossum" to show at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fetch the current category, then grab posts. So, try

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);

$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => $category );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added that to my template now I'm getting 'Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /mnt/www/wordpress/wp-includes/query.php on line 1450'

Comment: I have flagged this to be moved this to the StackOverflow for wordpress

Answer (score 0):

```
$title_tagged_posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tag' => strtolower( get_the_title() )
) );

while ( $title_tagged_posts_query->have_posts() ) : $title_tagged_posts_query->the_post();
    //Output whatever you want here.
endwhile;
```